# Django project: Spam bots spam all over my Sentry.io Account (Invalid HTTP_HOST header)

Tags: django, sentry, spam, spam-prevention

I have a django project running in production with gunicorn. It is connected to [sentry.io](https://sentry.io) for comfortable error logging.

There are a lot of spambots causing `Invalid HTTP_HOST header`, because they try to access it by ip, which is not allowed by django`s `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting. Those Spam Bots fill up my sentry plan limits, and after a while other errors are not logged anymore.

**What would be a simple and elegant solution to this?** I already thought about some, but they all have caveats:

1. **Filter out requests with wrong hosts in an earlier stage**, e.g. the nginx - Good idea, but I would like to be able to configure allowed hosts in django settings
2. **Catch** `Invalid HTTP_HOST header` **error** in django and not send to sentry: Good idea, but then I do not have invalid http host header error handling at all in sentry
3. **I would like to log one error per host and url per day or something like that** - But then I have to code a custom ratelimiter, which persists infos. Seems like a complex solution

What are your thought on this. Do you have other ideas? What would be the most elegant and less comlicated solution?

Comment: If the below-given answer worked for you consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Nginx to block any request that has an Invalid HTTP_HOST header

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    if ($http_host !~* ^(example.com|www.example.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    # rest of your Nginx configuration goes here
}
```

This way, you can still configure your allowed hosts in Django settings, while filtering out requests with invalid host headers at the proxy server.